# Enumerating a boolean in C

Tags: c, enum

This is one way to make a boolean in C.

```
typedef enum {
    false = 1 == 0,
    true = 0 == 0
} bool;
```

Recently I made some like

```
typedef enum {
    true = ~(int)0, //true is the opposite of false
    false = (int)0  //the smallest enum is equal to sizeof int
} bool;

int main(void) {
    return false;
}
```

Can this be improved upon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to the ANSI book:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants of type `int`

So the cast is redundant:

```
typedef enum {
    true = ~0,
    false = 0
} bool;
```

Also, in C, a "true" value is anything other than zero, so `~0` is no more "true" than `1` - might as well keep it simple:

```
typedef enum {
    false = 0,
    true = 1
} bool;
```

In fact, `0` and `1` are the standard choice for representing boolean values where there's no native boolean type (for example, the `bit` type in SQL uses `0`/`1`).

Now you might ask yourself, "so - did we just redefine zero and one?" - well, we certainly did. As an experiment in using `typedef`/`enum` it's okay. But don't use it in actual C code, because it'll make `if` clauses unnecessarily complex.

For example, let's say we want to compare `str` and `str2` and to do something if they're not equal. We'll use `strcmp` which compares two strings and returns 0 if they're equal.

```
// without bool
if(strcmp(str1,str2))
{
    ...
}

// with bool
if(strcmp(str1,str2) == 0 ? false : true)
{
    ...
}
```

In conclusion, as an experiment your code is OK and can be slightly improved. Generally, the lack of `bool` type in C seems scary at first, but it's actually quite convenient when you get used to it.

Comment: It would be less surprising to put `false` before `true` so that the members are listed in ascending order as usual in an `enum`.

Comment: My C++ instructor comes from Pascal, and would always require explicit casts... I guess it stuck.